# Remove Hover Styling on Kendo Treeview

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am trying to remove the hover styling on the [kendoui treeview component](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/index.html) so that when you hover over an item in the treeview it does not have a border / background image etc. I have gotten rid of everything but the border as it looks like there are additional styles that are at play that I cannot seem to locate. Here is my css so far... (in addition to the default theme)

```
  .k-treeview .k-in.k-state-hover{
    background-image:none;
    background-color:#fff;border:none;


}

.k-treeview .k-in.k-state-selected{
    background-image:none;
    background-color:#fff;color:#000;border:none;}
```

Currently it is just showing a border which looks to be black as opposed to the grey one that was there before I added the styles above... Any idea what I can do to get rid of this stubborn border?

Comment: Use developer tools to inspect the element (in specific look at computed styles) and find the style that applies

Answer (score 3):

With the addition of this style embedded on the page I was able to get it to do what I wanted. I believe this was partially related to how the css was being loaded (order) in multiple different sharepoint webparts on the same page...

```
.k-treeview .k-in.k-state-hover, .k-treeview .k-in.k-state-selected {
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 3px;
}
```

Comment: @Nick I had to use the inspector in chrome to figure out which styles to remove, in my scenario there was about a dozen properties that I had to override over 3 different selectors.

Comment: Ideally, it would be nice to flag an option in the kendo control to disable the hover state instead of having to write an addition override to counter the kendo toggle.

Answer (score 2):

Coupled with the use of `.k-state-disabled`, it appears I might have found a slightly better CSS solution.

The nodes don't move at all, and it appears completely disabled.

```
.k-treeview .k-in.k-state-hover,
.k-treeview .k-in.k-state-focused,
.k-treeview .k-in.k-state-selected {
    border-color:transparent;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

I've also added some JavaScript to prevent the expanding of the nodes, and disabling of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this helped:

```
.k-window-action .k-state-hover {
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
```

P.S.: "border-color: transparent" caused slight move on hover